# Why is setattr not working when importing differently in python?

Tags: python

I changed the value of a constant using setattr.

```py
from core import constants

setattr(constants, "VERSION", "1.0.0")
```

Now, this still prints 0.1.0 (The older value defined in the constants)

```py
from core.constants import VERSION

print(VERSION)
```

But, this prints 1.0.0 as expected.

```py
from core import constants

print(constants.VERSION)
```

Why is this? And what can I do to change the value in first case too.

EDIT:

The `constants` is not actually a constants.py file but a directory `constants` with `__init__.py` file. And have the following content.

```py
VERSION = "0.1.0"
```

Comment: Please show the constants file

Comment: `setattr` itself works fine either way. The question is whether you're referring to the same object or not.

Comment: Made an update about the way constants are defined.

Comment: Namespaces.  With `from core.constants import VERSION` the name VERSION is brought into the local namespace.  With `from core import constants` the name constants is brought into the local namespace, and VERSION remains in the namespace of the `constants` module.